# Azure web api Unauthorized 401

Tags: api, azure, authentication

I have some code that used to call Azure Scheduler to get a token,  then using that token, make restful calls.  Works a treat.

So i decided to adopt the code into a new app but this time call my own web api hosted on azure. The API is registered in Active directory I have created a secret key etc.  When i initiliaze my static httpclient it fetches a token succesfully.

But when i make a call to the API using the token for auth, the response is a 401 "unauthorized",  below is the code.

```
 public static class SchedulerHttpClient
{
    const string SPNPayload = "resource={0}&client_id={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret={2}";

    private static Lazy<Task<HttpClient>> _Client = new Lazy<Task<HttpClient>>(async () =>
    {
        string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"];
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        await MainAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return client;
    });

    public static Task<HttpClient> ClientTask => _Client.Value;

    private static async Task MainAsync(HttpClient client)
    {
        string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenantId"];
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientSecret"];

        string token = await AcquireTokenBySPN(client, tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); //TODO ssmith: const or localization
    }

    private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenBySPN(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var payload = String.Format(SPNPayload,
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ARMResource"]),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

        var body = await HttpPost(client, tenantId, payload).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return body.access_token;
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> HttpPost(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string payload)
    {
        var address = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenEndpoint"], tenantId);
        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(address, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status:  {0}", response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Content: {0}", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }//TODO: start removing tests

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is the class that creates a httpclient and gets its authorization.

```
public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(string apiURL)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask;
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(apiURL);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return responseContent;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

The above code is a quick lift of my old code simply to test if i can get any results. but as stated it returns a 401.

My question is, is my old code to get authorization incorrect?

```
<add key="ARMResource" value="https://management.core.windows.net/" />
<add key="TokenEndpoint" value="https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token" />
<add key="BaseAddress" value="https://mysite.azurewebsites.net" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, This particular issue was cause by the incorrect "ARMresource" in the case of a web api it required me to change it to the client id.

[Source of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332313/unable-to-use-bearer-token-to-access-aad-secure-web-api)

Seems my issue was the same, however i suspect i may be able to omit the resource entirely from my SPNPayload string.